# How to determine if a Promise is supported by the browser

Tags: javascript, promise, browser-detection, es6-promise

Does anyone know, using Modernizr or otherwise, if there is a way to detect if the Promise feature is enabled in a browser?

I have a polyfill for the functionality, but only want to apply it if the browser does not have a native implementation.

Comment: Right here: http://caniuse.com/#search=promise

Comment: `var supported = ('Promise' in window);`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update Dec 11 - 2016:** All evergreen versions of browsers now support promises. They are safe to use.

---

**Update Nov 14 - 2016:** Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE all now have experimental support for promises in their dev channels. The specification has settled. I would still not rely on the implementation just yet and would use a library but this might change in a few months.

---

No browsers support promises natively in a reliable way. The specification might change - at least for a few more months. My suggestion is use a fast promise library like Bluebird.

If you want to check if native promises are enabled - you can do :

```
if(typeof Promise !== "undefined" && Promise.toString().indexOf("[native code]") !== -1){
    //here
}
```

As others suggested, just checking if there is a `Promise` object can be done by `if(Promise)` but I strongly suggest against it since different libraries have different APIs for creation of promises etc.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `typeof Promise !== "undefined"`, since `typeof` returns a string?

Comment: @PaulRoub yeah, it started as `Promise !== undefined` but I realized the identifier might not be declared.

Comment: This is particularly useful if you want to know if the `Promise` you're working with is native or a polyfill. Unfortunately, many polyfills (including the one used by Traceur) do not set a flag to indicate that they aren't native.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder why would you care though?

Comment: Native Promises (well native `Promise.all()`) + Traceur generators are currently broken: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/1955

Comment: What would be the reverse of this? `===` undefined and `=== -1`?

Answer (score 16):

## Not so fast.

This **throws** when "Promise" is undefined:

```
if (Promise)
  // do code
```

This **never** throws:

```
if (window.Promise)
  // do code

if (typeof Promise !== 'undefined')
  // do code
```

and yes the window object can be relied upon in a browser environment.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(window, 'Promise', { get() { throw Error(); }});`

Answer (score 6):

To create a 'supported' flag without carrying around an object reference:

```
var canPromise = !! window.Promise;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to create one in a `try/catch` block:

```
var promiseSupport = false;
try {
    var promise = new Promise(function (x, y) {});
    promiseSupport = true;
} catch (e) {}
```

Check `promiseSupport` to see whether or not it fails.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/VccmN/2/)**