# Defer Loading of javascript for google page insights

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, deferred

I have a code for defer loading of javascript I am wondering if the code will load the scripts in order (`JQuery.min` first) according to where they are in the code ?

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {


var element01 = document.createElement("script");
element01.src = "js/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element01);

var element02 = document.createElement("script");
element02.src = "js/plugins.js";
document.body.appendChild(element02);

var element03 = document.createElement("script");
element03.src = "js/scripts.js";
document.body.appendChild(element03);


var element04 = document.createElement("script");
element04.src = "js/SmoothScroll.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element04);

var element05 = document.createElement("script");
element05.src = "js/contact-form.js";
document.body.appendChild(element05);

}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

If this doesn't load `JQuery.min` first and then the other js files how can you make JQuery.min the first script to load and then the rest after that has loaded?
Also I am guessing for example the `contact-form.js` will be one of the first to finish loading as it's small so this could cause the `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` I'm guessing because the JQuery.min hasn't finished downloading so how would you solved this ? I'm guessing an listener / if finished loading load the others else wait...
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are correct, you are calling them in order by you can't be certain they will come back in the same order.  Callbacks or promises would solve this.

Comment: could you use a promise to load jquery.min and then on the resolution of that load the rest?

Comment: I'll look into this I've next to no knowledge on promises

Comment: Unfortunately, neither do I, but their ability to do synchronous things seems like it fits your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found here [Load jQuery with JavaScript using Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638221/load-jquery-with-javascript-using-promises)

```
function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve  reject) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.onerror = reject;
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    });
}

function loadjQuery() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // already loaded and ready to go
        return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
        return loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js');
    }
}


// Usage:
loadjQuery().then(function() {
    // code here that uses jQuery
}, function() {
    // error loading jQuery
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but does the script have to be appended to the head? Why not after the closing body tag? Will this code using promises work cross browser?
Another small issue, potentially, Google will punish page load if the full render (on load) takes too long, not just first render. Will this code not infringe on the native onload? This would be an amazing solution, just wondering if it works and how.

Comment: @ptts I don't think it should matter where it is appended to. according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516959/how-to-determine-if-a-promise-is-supported-by-the-browser it is cross browser compatible

Comment: Wow, this is great then. However, which one of the replies in the link is the one which works? There is some controversy if I read all answers.

Comment: I looked at the most updated one from december of last year

Comment: I assume I use var element05 = document.createElement("script"); etc etc where // code here that uses jQuery is also are there any downsides to this approach vs pure javascript?

Comment: yes, that is where you would load your other scripts. This is pure javascript

Comment: Whats browser support like with promise

Comment: @Neths according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516959/how-to-determine-if-a-promise-is-supported-by-the-browser is cross browser compatible

Comment: My problem was I loaded scripts after jQuery and some of them have dependencies on others. For such scripts I have put script.async=false; script.defer=true to make them run in order

Answer (score 1):

This is quick, but I think it should work.

```
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element01 = document.createElement("script");
    element01.src = "js/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element01);

    element01.onload = function() {
        var element02 = document.createElement("script");
        element02.src = "js/plugins.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element02);

        var element03 = document.createElement("script");
        element03.src = "js/scripts.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element03);


        var element04 = document.createElement("script");
        element04.src = "js/SmoothScroll.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element04);

        var element05 = document.createElement("script");
        element05.src = "js/contact-form.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element05);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to satisfy googles page insights / above the fold on my site files so looking for a solution that loads the jquery.min.js and also gets rid of the above fold warnings on the file

Comment: @Neths so, you want to be able to load jquery.min.js and once it is fully loaded then load the rest?  Would that solve your problem?

Comment: I assume it would because if the juqery.min.js is fully loaded first it won't throw the $ is not defined error

Comment: this throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input